# Eclipse not auto-generating IDs from XML files for R.java

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

As far as I understand from the Android manual, IDs that contain the "+" (plus) sign automatically get generated in the corresponding R.java file in Eclipse. However, when I attempt to run my program, Eclipse says that the ID cannot be resolved and offers me as a possible solution to manually add that as an entry in the "id" file. But it puts the value of 0 as a default value. 
How do I make it have a value just like the other IDs have their own hex value (i.e. 0x7f03000d)?

Comment: Is "automatic build" activated? Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project? It's also possible that one of your XML files contains an error. When that happens the Android build process just stops and the R class file does not get re-generated. Check all files for possible errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check the files names in the folder res

They should not contain spaces or special characters and must be lowercase